# How to count number of lines in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uibezierpath

I need to count number of lines in my `UITextField`.

My `UITextField` has an array of `UIBezierPath`, to draw text along an `UIImage`.

```
UIBezierPath *rect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_image.frame cornerRadius:0];
[_txt addSubview:_image];
_txt.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[rect];
```

Obviously, number of lines is different because there is an exclusion path and this common way,

```
 CGSize size  = [_txt.text
                sizeWithFont:_txt.font constrainedToSize:(CGSize){_txt.frame.size.width, INTMAX_MAX}
                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

returns a wrong result.

Note: `_txt` is an `UITextField`.

thanks.

---

#### Test case:

[image]

Ref: http://goo.gl/Ch9al6

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size

Answer (score 0):

In `UITextInputProtocol` there's a method there called `firstRectForRange:` ([doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextinput_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/firstRectForRange:.)).  This might do the trick.  Try it with a text range set to the end of the backing string.

```
// given a UITextView* called textView
UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
UITextPosition *p0 = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:textView.text.length-1];
UITextPosition *p1 = [textView positionFromPosition:p0 offset:1];
UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:p0 toPosition:p1];
CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
// rect will be given in the coordinate space of textView
```

Disclaimer:  I haven't tried this even for a simple case, and yours looks non-trivial.