# Take Screenshot of Textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Am making an iOS application which captures screenshot of a textview filled with some image. The problem is that the screen shot captures the entire screen.
How do I take screen shot of UITextView using Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.textField.bounds.size, false, 0);
self.textField.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.textField.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let copied = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
imageView.image = copied
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: thanks it helps. can you tell me how to get number of line exists in UITextView using swift

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size

Answer (score 1):

You can save any view as image by using drawViewHierarchyInRect method

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.textView.bounds.size, false, 0);
self.textText.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.textView.frame.size.width, self.textView.frame.size.height),afterScreenUpdates:true)
var screenShot:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: i want screenshot of all data available in textview means when i enter multiple line then scroll appear than it take screenshot only those portion that display on screen , i want all data screenshot without extending height of textview

Comment: @ScientistGetAns Unfortunately there is no direct way to achieve what you are looking for. A possible workaround : 1) before taking screenShot extend textView  height so it will show all the lines 2) take screenShot 3) set textView height to its original height. With this workaround user will not even see height change so it could be a good workaround

Comment: done, can you tell me how to get number of line exists in UITextView using swift

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good but missing is `scale` which is `necessary` in `context`.

Use `UIView's drawViewHierarchyInRect` mehtod to capture screen.

```
//Use screen scale for better images
let screenScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
//create context 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourView.bounds.size, false, screenScale);
//use view for drawing
yourView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(yourView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
//get captured image
let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//last dump context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Another sloution** : use `UIView's layer's renderInContext`

```
//Use screen scale for better images
let screenScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
//create context 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourView.bounds.size, false, screenScale);
//use view for drawing
yourView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
//get captured image
let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//last dump context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```