# How to get UITextView number of lines using TextKit 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Since iOS 16, TextKit 2 has replaced TextKit 1 for `UITextView` which means `layoutManager` is out and `textLayoutManager` is in. However, a number of the properties from the old are not in the new. How can I calculate the number of lines in a `UITextView` using TextKit 2? Below is the TextKit 1 implementation.

```
extension UITextView {
    var numberOfLines: Int {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            // TextKit 2

            let layout = textLayoutManager // new layout manager
        } else {
            // TextKit 1

            let layout = layoutManager // old layout manager
            var lines = 0
            var index = 0
            var lineRange = NSRange()
            
            while index < layout.numberOfGlyphs {
                layout.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
                index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
                lines += 1
            }
            return max(1, lines)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NSTextLayoutManager seems there is no options to access properties to calculate number of lines from UITextView.

But Why you don't try this simple process for getting number of lines from UITextView ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36626498/3683408

Comment: @Ram dividing the content height by the font's line height doesn't work on the keystroke that breaks the line, only the following keystroke. The code in my answer is bulletproof for all edge cases (keystroke, autocomplete, paste). I just want to find the TextKit 2 variant.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `enumerateTextLayoutFragments` to get the 'real' number of lines, which are divided by '\n'.

```swift
var count = 0
textView.textLayoutManager?.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: textView.textLayoutManager?.documentRange.location,
                                                         options: [.ensuresLayout, .ensuresExtraLineFragment],
                                                         using: { _ in
    count += 1
    return true // keep going
})
```